# how can i craete GKE NEG service type with terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

```
## name_space ##
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx"
  }
}

### Deployment ###
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "test" {
  for_each = local.deployment
  metadata {
    name      = each.key
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test.metadata.0.name
  }
  spec {
    replicas = each.value.replicas
    selector {
      match_labels = each.value.selector
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = each.value.selector
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image = each.value.image
          name  = each.key
          port {
            container_port = each.value.int_port
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
### Service ###
resource "kubernetes_service" "test" {
  for_each = local.service
  metadata {
    name      = each.key
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test.metadata.0.name
    annotations = {
      "cloud.google.com/neg" : "ingress: true"
    }
  }
  spec {
    selector = each.value.selector
    type     = each.value.type
    port {
      port        = each.value.int_port
      target_port = each.value.ext_port
    }
  }
}

locals {
  deployment = {
    nginx = {
      selector = {
        app = "nginx"
      }
      image    = "nginx"
      replicas = 2
      int_port = 80
    }
  }
}

locals {
  service = {
    nginx-svc = {
      selector = {
        app = "nginx"
      }
      type        = "ClusterIP"
      int_port    = 80
      ext_port    = 80
    }
}
```

It fails to create with the following error:
│ Error: admission webhook "neg-annotation.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: error parsing value of NEG annotation "cloud.google.com/neg" on service "nginx"/"nginx-svc": NEG annotation is invalid.
│
│   with kubernetes_service.test["nginx-svc"],
│   on k8s.tf line 38, in resource "kubernetes_service" "test":
│   38: resource "kubernetes_service" "test"
Can you help?

Comment: Shouldn't be the annotation in json format: '{"ingress": true }'

Answer (score 0):

I think the annotation format is incorrect.

Should be like:

```
cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
```